# accessing parent property values in child class

Tags: php

I have a strange issue where I set values in a parent class but cannot access those values in a child class extending the parent.

```
class Parent
{
    protected $config;

    public function load($app)
    {
        $this->_config();
        $this->_load($app);
    }

    private function _config()
    {
        $this->config = $config; //this holds the config values
    }

    private function _load($app)
    {
        $app = new $app();
        $this->index;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    public function index()
    {
        print_r($this->config); // returns an empty array
    }
}

$test = new Parent();
$test->load('app');
```

when I do that i get an empty array printed out. But if I do this then I am able to access those config values.

```
private function _load($app)
{
    $app = new $app();
    $app->config = $this->config
    $app->index;

}
```

and

```
class Child extends Parent
{
    public $config;
          ....
}
```

then I can access the config data from the parent.

Comment: What is the `app` class?

Comment: the app class its the Child class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing the values before anything is initialized there. First you have to set the values.

Example: call a method is the parent class, which set the value, on the contructor of the child class.

```
class Child extends Parent
{
    public function __construct() {
       $this -> setConfig(); //call some parent method to set the config first
    }
    public function index()
    {
        print_r($this->config); // returns an empty array
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** You also seem to confused about concept of OOP

```
class Parent { ..... }
class child extends Parent { ..... }
$p = new Parent(); // will contain all method and properties of parent class only
$c = new Child(); // will contain all method and properties of child class and parent class
```

But, you have to work with parent methods and properties just the same way you would do in the normal object.

Lets See another example:

```
class Parent { 
     protected $config = "config";
}
class Child extends Parent {
     public function index() {
           echo $this -> config; // THis will successfully echo "config" from the parent class
     }
}
```

But another example

```
class Parent { 
     protected $config;
}
class Child extends Parent {
     public function index() {
           echo $this -> config; //It call upon the parent's $config, but so far there has been no attempt to set an values on it, so it will give empty output.
     }
}
```

Comment: hey starx, after you first attempted to help me the first time a week ago i redid my code to make it more streamlined. Now i'm back with the same issue. I thought that extending a parent class will inherit all property values.

Comment: I'm sure they are just typos, but the scope resolution is incorrect in your updated examples for `$config`.

Comment: @MikePurcell, Oops (O.o), fixed it. Thanks

Comment: oh i see, hmmm so the fact that i'm setting up the value to my $config property THEN calling a new object of a child class won't help. I need to pass in the config some other way?

Comment: the explanation helped me realize an error in my code. Thx

Answer (score 1):

It's because the property in the parent is protected. Set it to public and you can access it in child classes. Or alternatively, create a method in the parent class which returns the config:

```
public function getConfig()
{
    return $this->config;
}
```

Comment: @MikePurcell, $config is protected, while destroy that creating a public accessor.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "destroy" but you are correct, child class should still have access to protected $config, thought it was private for some reason.

Comment: remember that a protected parent property can only be accessed within the parent or child classes. I have assumed that the OP is using 'echo $app->config;' or something similar. This is an explanation for the OP: http://au.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: i thought that extending the parent class will allow the child to access property data. is this not the case? and also protected should work because i'm extending not calling it outside of the class

Comment: @Starx: I get what you are saying about "destroying" with the public accessor. It does depend if he wants it accessible outside of the class or not, but you should always try to use accessors when possible. I mis-spoke with regards to public, because he may in fact want it to remain protected.

Comment: @Eli, the protected value will be available within the methods of the child class, but if you're trying to access it externally - e.g. via an instance of the class, or anywhere outside of the child class definition, then it will not be accessible. See the link in my previous comment for an official explanation

Comment: then i have this setup correctly, the visibility isn't an issue. its the fact that the property return null or an empty array that if my issue.